# Nonzero return code error while installing TextBlob

Tags: python, textblob

I have been trying to install Python TextBlob, but I am getting this error:

> Now downloading textblob packages
>   [localhost] run: python -m textblob.download_corpora
>   [localhost] out: /home/naren/VirtualEnvironment/bin/python: No module named textblob
>   [localhost] out:
>
> Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
>
> Requested: python -m textblob.download_corpora
>   Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/naren/VirtualEnvironment && source bin/activate && python -m textblob.download_corpora"
>
> Aborting.
>   Disconnecting from localhost... done.
>   run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Comment: I have edited your question to remove some unnecessary details, and moved your error message into a quote block instead of a code block so the syntax highlighting is removed. I've also edited your title to include the error description.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this installation? Which OS?

The textblob homepage gives this short installation instruction:

```
$ pip install -U textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Since you get this error:

```
No module named textblob
```

I'm guessing the second part (downloading the data files) runs without the first part (installing the module) or that the first part failed somehow.

Try reinstalling using the above commands, or [using conda](http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/install.html#with-conda)

```
$ conda config --add channels https://conda.binstar.org/sloria
$ conda install textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

You need to [install Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/index.html#installation-instructions) to get Conda to run of course.